# Load external text in HTML

Tags: html, text, external

I want to load a static text file from an HTML document without using Javascript or any server side language.
I've tried using `object` tag as follows:

```
<object id="information" name="information" data="http://www.example.com/data.txt"></object>
```

But it didn't work. Is it possible to do this? If so, which tag should I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use an `<iframe src="..." />`.

Comment: Are there any security hazards or is it safe to use an `iframe` in your own website?

Comment: any time your loading an external source there are risks unless you control the source information.  I think loading a text file should be safe though.  Although someone could put some nasty verbiage in the file which your users would see :)  that is unless you parse the text before display.

Comment: @JohnDoe: This has exactly the same security issues that outer page itself has.  If you're displaying a page from an external site, there aren't any issues, due to the same-origin policy.  (unless that other site tries to exploit a hole in the browser or a plugin)